# multiply values and apply style in Datatables

Tags: datatables, rendering

I would like to understand how to multiply column values and apply style in Datatables.

Currently my columns section looks like this :

```
"columns": [
                { data: "id" },
                { data: "brand" },
                { data: "description" },
                { data: "nb_ref" },
                { sortable : false, data: "cost", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ' ', '.', 2, '€' )  },
            ]
```

what I would like in the 5th column is to multiply the "cost" by the "nb_ref" (the value of the 4th column) and still apply the number format.

Any idea about how to achieve ?

thanks

Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984339/render-currency-and-symbol-and-combine-with-data-from-a-different-cell) I think you can do it like this

```
"columns": [
            { data: "id" },
            { data: "brand" },
            { data: "description" },
            { data: "nb_ref" },
            { sortable : false, data: "cost", render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                var nb_ref = row['nb_ref'];
                var cost = row['cost'];  
                var total = nb_ref * cost;
                return $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ' ', '.', 2, '€' ).display(total);                        
               } 
            },
        ]
```